# Swift custom TableViewcell , however the mapView seems to exceed the bounds

Tags: swift, uitableview, mapkit

I am creating a custom tableview cell which has a Mapview embedded in the tableviewcell. Everything looks fine but the mapview seems to exceed the limits of the screen. Need some help.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I am using a storyboard for this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constraint on the right side of your mapView. If you are using storyboard, click the "Add New Constraints" button, and add a constraint on the right side of the mapView, preferably the same number as what you had on the left.

If you are not using the storyboard, add the constraint programmatically with this tutorial, as I myself use storyboard.

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/auto-layout-programmatically/